# Jquery Multiple Click Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am dynamically creating objects which construct a view and bind events to the constructed view when clicked.  However, the click event is always attaching itself to the last created object.  I do want to have the same click event for each object, but the data that I am passing to a new class is unique per instance.

Object creation:

```
$.each(data,function(i,json)
        {
            var channelWrapper = new ChannelDisplayView(that.channelContainer, json);           
            that.channelContainer.append(channelWrapper.createView());
        });
```

ChannelDisplayView.js

```
function ChannelDisplayView(parent, data){
    this.parent = parent;
    this.data = data;
}
ChannelDisplayView.prototype.createView = function(){
    this.channelWrapper = $("<div/>").addClass("channelDisplay").attr("id", this.data.fullName);
    this.channelTitle = $("<div/>").addClass("channelTitle").html(this.data.fullName);
    this.channelSource = $("<div/>").addClass("sourceType").html(this.data.sourceType);
    this.channelWrapper.append(this.channelTitle);      
    this.channelWrapper.append(this.channelSource); 

    that = this;
    this.channelWrapper.unbind().on("click",function(event){
        ControllersSingleton.getInstance().getProgramController().setupPage(that.data);     
    });

    return this.channelWrapper;
}
```

As you can see each class will hold its own JSON data and this should be used to pass to an instance of another controller if the "div" is clicked.  The data being sent no matter what div I click is always from the last created object.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Any chance of jsFiddle or jsBin ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind an event handler to your whole document and listen for all events of a certain type, responding with a callback if the event target matches a certain selector.  For instance:

```
$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function(e){
  console.log('.some-class element clicked.');
});
```

That code will listen for any clicks on the document, and *if the target matches the selector in the second parameter*, it will execute the callback function in the third parameter.

I often find it best to use a method like this when I am dynamically adding elements to the DOM.

Comment: I did try this earlier using the ID since that is the only thing that is unique, and somehow it is still hitting the last event made.

Comment: @urnotsam any chance you could put your code in a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I will try to throw one together

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created a global `that` which on each loop iteration is being overwrote with `that = this`.

Instead of calling append on `that.channelContainer` try using the instance you have created like `channelWrapper.channelContainer.append...`.  channelWrapper is scoped to the loop iteration.